# Linked list removeLast() function is not actually removing anything

Tags: java, linked-list

Can't figure out why it's not removing the last node.....and I have the normal remove() function working fine, that is not the issue.

Is there anything wrong with it?

```
 public T removeLast()
    {
        Node<T> currentNode, prevNode;
        currentNode = this.getHead();
        while(currentNode != null)
        {

            if(currentNode.getNext()==null)
            {
//               prevNode = this.getPrevious(currentNode);
//               prevNode.setNext(null);
                this.remove(currentNode);
               return null;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is my remove function, I dont think it works for the last node

```
   private boolean remove(Node<T> aNode)
    {
        if(aNode==null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> prevNode, nextNode;
            prevNode = this.getPrevious(aNode);
            if(aNode.getNext()==null){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                nextNode = aNode.getNext();
                prevNode.setNext(nextNode);
            }

            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why did you tag the question as `c`?

Comment: Why are you returning 'null' no matter what?

Comment: @NeilLocketz well it has to return something. I don't think that is the issue though...is it?

Comment: I would a) debug and b) check if `remove` has any issue with the last node.

Comment: @SJuan76 I think you are right....remove doesn't work with the last one. I have added that function to the post

Comment: I am also right when I tell you to debug it yourself... check what instructions is really executing your program. Most IDEs are a great help for this.

Comment: What is the reason behind `if(aNode.getNext()==null) {
                return true; 
            }`?  You're just confirming that it is the last node and without doing anything return `true`

Comment: I think you'll find that your `remove` method doesn't work on the first node either.

Comment: You should use a sentinel (head/tail) based approach.  That makes everything very easy.  Only one simple method for adding/removing, which is called by methods such `addFront`, `addBack`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are implementing a doubly linked list? Your remove function actually refers to the previous node from the given node in the remove function.

The issue appears to be when it's the last node, you're not actually doing anything, you're just returning true.

To remove the last node in the list, you need to set the Next reference on the previous node to null and then return.

```
private boolean remove(Node<T> aNode)
{
    if(aNode==null)
    {
        return true;   // not sure why this returns true... false perhaps?
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> prevNode, nextNode;
        prevNode = this.getPrevious(aNode);
        // you will also need to check prevNode for null, in the case of the first node.
        if(prevNode == null) {
            this.setNext(aNode.getNext());
            return true;
        }
        else if(aNode.getNext()==null){
            prevNode.setNext(null);  // set the previous node's next (aNode) to null.
            return true;
        }
        else{
            nextNode = aNode.getNext();
            prevNode.setNext(nextNode);
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Note that since you seem to have a doubly linked list here, why not use the previous node of the last element to find out which one to remove, rather than iterating through from the head?

Comment: Don't you need a special case for the **first** node as well?

Comment: Yes, you would need to check before assigning prevNode to the argument node's reference. If you do that, then the logic becomes the same, only you set the node reference on 'this' to null.